# NodeJs How to use Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to Node, and I am trying to learn Sequelize, 
As it is a popular and easy to work with ORM like Hibernate,
I am using MySql for implementing an example to work with,
However, I am facing an issue to make a simple implementation of the same,
**I installed the library using the following commands -**

```
1. npm install --save sequelize
2. npm install --save mysql2
```

**I have two files -**
1. app.js (main code)
2. code.js (Model class)

**1. app.js -**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const code = require('./code');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('junit', 'root', 'root', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'/* one of 'mysql' | 'mariadb' | 'postgres' | 'mssql' */,
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

  code.findAll().then(codes => {
    console.log("All users:", JSON.stringify(codes, null, 4));
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**2. code.js -**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');


module.exports = (sequelize) => {
class Code extends Model {}
  Code.init({
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdBy: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    // options
  });
}
```

**But I am getting the following error on running my app.js file -**

```
/home/user/office/pocs/test/app.js:26
  code.findAll().then(codes => {
       ^

TypeError: code.findAll is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/office/pocs/test/app.js:26:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:526:15)
    at startMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/node.js:439:3)
```

**I am referring this Doc - 

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/getting-started

but the examples don't contain the full code, imports, etc

So it's a little difficult to understand,

Can someone please help?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a few changes:

First, you need to return the `Code` class inside of your function.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  class Code extends Sequelize.Model {}
  Code.init({
    ...
  }, {
    sequelize,
    // options
  });
  return Code;
}
```

Second, you are exporting a function inside of `./code`. You must call this fuction with the sequelize object you created:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('junit', 'root', 'root', {
  ...
});

const code = require('./code')(sequelize);
```

Lastly, I would recommend you maintain the casing convention and refer to the `Code` model in titlecase during the import, e.g. `const Code = require('./code')(sequelize);`

Comment: Hey! now I'm getting a "ReferenceError: Model is not defined", is it to be some more import or is it part of the sequelize import?

Comment: I've updated the answer. The `Model` class exists on the `Sequelize` import